# convert list to dictionary using Python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am a newbie :)

I need to convert this simple list to a dictionary :

```
[('Host', '127.0.0.1:8000'), ('Connection', 'keep-alive'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'), ('Test_data_Header_Key', 'Test_Data_Header_value'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'), ('Postman-Token', '3b17e573-90d6-e5fe-26cb-a9488f9b22e0'), ('Accept', '*/*'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.6')]
```

The output will be `{"Host":"127.0.0.1.8000", "Connection" : "Keep-alive" ....}`

Appreciate your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: `dict(my_list)`

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate. I hope you find the solution to your problem there (or simply what Rawings suggested in his comment). If not, feel free to edit your question explaining why the approaches there did not work or ask another question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dict` constructor already does this for you:

```
dict([('Host', '127.0.0.1:8000'), ('Connection', 'keep-alive'), ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'), ('Test_data_Header_Key', 'Test_Data_Header_value'), ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'), ('Postman-Token', '3b17e573-90d6-e5fe-26cb-a9488f9b22e0'), ('Accept', '*/*'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br'), ('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.6')])
```